# I cannot add the class "unread" to the append content of a certain data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the "unread" class to an append content with a specific data-id. The following line of code works fine in the browser console. However, when the code is run it does not add the class "unread".

```
var idMessage = message[message.length-1].id;
$('#visitors').find('h5[data-id=' + idMessage + ']').addClass('unread');
```

The goal is to add "unread" in the following line of code:

```
$("#visitors").append('<h5 class="' + state + '" data-id=' + visitors[i].idSession + '>' + visitors[i].visitorOnline + '</h5>');
```

I will provide you with a code snippet

```
<div id="conexion-chat">
    <button id="btn-conexion-chat" onclick="initWebSocket();">Iniciar chat</button>
</div>
<div id="display-chat" style="display: none;">
    <div id="visitors"></div>
    <br />
    <textarea id="chatRoomField" rows="10" cols="30" readonly></textarea> <br/>
    <input id="sendField" value="" type="text">
    <button id="sendButton" onclick="send_message();">Enviar</button>
</div>

function initWebSocket(){
    $('#conexion-chat').css('display', 'none');
    $('#display-chat').css('display', '');
    
    websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/o/echo");
    
    websocket.onopen = function (event) {
        websocket.send(json_user());
    };
    
    websocket.onclose = function(event) {
        localStorage.clear();
        console.log("DESCONECTADO");
    };
    
    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var message = event.data;
        processMessage(message);
    };
    
    websocket.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + event.data);
    };
}

function visitorSelected(event){
    var visitorSelected = $(event.target).data('id');       
    localStorage.setItem('visitorSelected', visitorSelected);   
    websocket.send(json_messages(visitorSelected, '${email}', '${read}'));
    document.getElementById("chatRoomField").innerHTML = "";
}
    
function processMessage(message){

    if(message == '${disconnected}'){
        document.getElementById("chatRoomField").innerHTML += "El patrocinador no se encuentra conectado." + "\n";
            
    }else {
            
        var json_message = JSON.parse(message);
        var visitorSelected = localStorage.getItem('visitorSelected');
            
        if(json_message.hasOwnProperty('message') && message.length > 0){
            var message = json_message.message;

            var text = "";
                
            if('${currentUserRol}' != '${rolPreferences}'){
                for(var i=0; i<message.length; i++){
                    text += message[i].from + ": " + message[i].message + "\n";
                    document.getElementById("chatRoomField").innerHTML = text;
                }
                        
            }else{
                if(message[message.length-1].id == visitorSelected || message[message.length-1].idTo == visitorSelected){
                    for(var i=0; i<message.length; i++){
                        text += message[i].from + ": " + message[i].message + "\n";
                        document.getElementById("chatRoomField").innerHTML = text;
                    }
                }else{
                    var idMessage = message[message.length-1].id;
                    $('#visitors').find('h5[data-id=' + idMessage + ']').addClass('unread');
                }   
            }
        }
            
        if(json_message.hasOwnProperty('visitors') && json_message.visitors.length > 0){
            var visitors = json_message.visitors;
            var state;              

            $("#visitors h5").remove();
                
            for (var i = 0; i < visitors.length; i++) {
                state = (visitors[i].idSession == visitorSelected)? "selected" : "not-selected";        
                $("#visitors").append('<h5 class="' + state + '" data-id=' + visitors[i].idSession + '>' + visitors[i].visitorOnline + '</h5>');
            }
                
            if(visitorSelected == null){
                $("#visitors h5:first-child").attr("class", "selected");
                visitorSelected = $("#visitors h5:first-child").attr("data-id");
                localStorage.setItem('visitorSelected', visitorSelected);
            }
        }
    }
}
    
$('#visitors').on('click', 'h5.not-selected', visitorSelected);
```

***Note: The entire code has not been submitted, but a code snippet.**

Thanks!

Regards!

Comment: Looks like the line with `addClass('unread')` is coming before `$("#visitors").append('<h5 class="' + state + '" data-id=' + visitors[i].idSession + '>' + visitors[i].visitorOnline + '</h5>');`

Comment: Right, the visitor list did not exist. Thanks!